# Capistrano error while deploy (command not found: sneakersctl)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm getting the following error while deploy, that can't find out what's going on.

Any ideas?

```
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError:
Exception while executing as deploy@###.###.##.##: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile.
We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
bundler: command not found: sneakersctl
```

Comment: Is [capistrano-sneakers](https://github.com/inventionlabsSydney/capistrano-sneakers) gem installed?

Comment: Might be worth to check if [this issue](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3272) is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the setting in sneakers.rb file to

```
set :sneakers_run_config, -> { true }
```